# Forcing two cylinders to touch when modeling

Tags: modeling, add-on, constraints

As the title said: how do you force two cylinders to always touch while modeling. What I want to achieve is that I can move or rotate one of the cylinders during modeling, but with a constraint so they keep touching. The final result is static, so the cylinders do not have to be able to slide along each other with a rig or something.

For context: I'm planning to write an extension with some tools to quickly model pioneering constructions in blender. For example something like this:[image: pioneering construction in blender]

Modeling these constructions becomes tedious quite quickly because the spars have to touch and when slightly moving spars not perpendicular to each other they tend to intersect or stop touching. That is why I ant to write such an extension.

But I was wondering what is the best way to implement something like this, or if I'm missing already existing tools that would be useful. I succeeded to force two spars to touch using bones as follows:

1. I added a bone to the first spar, along its length
2. I added a bone at the the tail of the first bone, constrained it's length to the sum of the radii of the two spars and constrained it's rotation to the be perpendicular to the first bone (90° around x-axis in XZY-Euler)
3. At the tail of the second bone I connected a third bone, with the same rotation constraint as the second has with respect to the first. The second spar is aligned with this bone

This setup succeeds to force two spars to touch, and I can move the joint by moving the second bone. But it is a bit buggy and requires manipulating bones to model the construction. Furthermore, this is approach is bound to become a mess of bones for larger constructions.

Because I'm writing an add-on, I also thought about defining an object representing the joint. When this joint is moved, it would update the positions and/or rotations of the spars that it connect accordingly. But I did not find any way to listen for changes to a certain type of object to trigger a script.

any help is highly appreciated!